# How to set a variable and a default in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to make an application in python Tkinter and I want the user to change the color of the screen, if the user wants to use the default color they don't do anything.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(bg='blue', command=askColor) # Here I set up a default=blue..and a command that asks for a differnt color
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(bg='blue')

def color():
    col=askcolor()
    root.configure(bg=col[1])

Button(root,text='Click Me to choose color',command=color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`askcolor` will ask client to choose the color but col value will be in tuple and in tuple in first there will be (r,b,g) and in second hex code. Like this ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), '#000000')

so we use col[1](Hex code) for bg.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped...is there also a way to do the same for a font, like a similar method to askfont(). I want to change the font family and size all in one dialog.

Comment: Nope there is not the same way you have to write a single code for a font